# github: are changes in pull request available in the target branch before merge

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

I saw a jenkins job which builds a jar for future deployment, and this Jenkins job will be triggered when a pull request made for the master branch.

My question is: does the code in pull request already in the master branch before the Merge happened? Otherwise, they will build a jar without the change in the Pull Request.

Comment: The job probably build the branch containing the pull request. Otherwise, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: the job just run a "mvn ... deploy" to release to the artifactory, this does run under the master branch. But, what do u mean build a branch?

Comment: Typically you configure Jenkins so that every time a pull request is created, it checks out the branch containing the pull request, and builds the code contained in that branch. In order to know if the pull request breaks the build or not.

Comment: which means if I do a merge from Integration branch to the master, the build should run under the Integration branch, right?

Comment: If you do a **pull request** from integration branch to master, typically, yes. But you realize we know absolutely nothing about your job configuration, so we can only guess, right?

Comment: cool, thx. I have figured it out from you help.